# Removing inverted duplicates from list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

So basically I have a list of tuples [(a,b)], from which i have to do some filtering. One job is to remove inverted duplicates such that if (a,b) and (b,a) exist in the list, I only take one instance of them. But the list comprehension has not been very helpful. How to go about this in an efficient manner?

Thanks

Comment: For your particular application, is it important to preserve the pair order when only one variant is in the list?  (For example, if the list consists of only `[(2,1)]`, could you "simplify" the list to `[(1,2)]`?  Most of the answers given below assume you need to preserve pairs without inverted duplicates, but the solution might be simpler if you don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps an efficient way to do so (*O(n log(n))*) would be to track the tuples (and their reverses) already added, using [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Set.html):

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set                                                                                                                                                                        

removeDups' :: Ord a => [(a, a)] -> Set.Set (a, a) -> [(a, a)]
removeDups' [] _ = []
removeDups' ((a, b):tl) s | (a, b) `Set.member` s = removeDups' tl s
removeDups' ((a, b):tl) s | (b, a) `Set.member` s = removeDups' tl s
removeDups' ((a, b):tl) s = ((a, b):rest) where
    s' = Set.insert (a, b) s
    rest = removeDups' tl s'

removeDups :: Ord a => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
removeDups l = removeDups' l (Set.fromList [])
```

The function `removeDups` calls the auxiliary function `removeDups'` with the list, and an empty set. For each pair, if it or its inverse are in the set, it is passed; otherwise, both it and its inverses are added, and the tail is processed.                        \

The complexity is *O(n log(n))*, as the size of the set is at most linear in *n*, at each step.

---

**Example**

```
...

main = do
    putStrLn $ show $ removeDups [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1)]
```

and

```
$ ghc ord.hs && ./ord
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ord.hs, ord.o )
Linking ord ...
[(1,2),(1,3)]
```

Comment: You don't have to check (b, a) membership if you already set both variants into the set.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil That is true. Thanks! Corrected.

Comment: This could also be expressed as a fold. For example, if order is important, then something like ``snd . foldr (\ pair@(a, b) acc@(seen, result) -> if pair `Set.member` seen || (b, a) `Set.member` seen then acc else (Set.insert pair seen, pair : result)) mempty``, or a version with `foldl'` if filtering should go the other direction.

Comment: then with this solution the problem is solver in insertion right?

Comment: @JonPurdy That's an excellent point - always pays to think if something is a `fold`. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielSanchez Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @AmiTavory, sorry I did not understood properly your code, I had check it now, and I understand now :). Very good solution

Comment: @DanielSanchez Thanks. I like the simplicity & reuse in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter them using your own function:

```
checkEqTuple :: (a, b) -> (a, b) -> Bool
checkEqTuple (x, y) (x', y') | (x==y' && y == x') = True
                             | (x==x' && y == y') = True
                             | otherwise          = False
```

then use [nubBy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nubBy)

```
Prelude Data.List> nubBy checkEqTuple [(1,2), (2,1)]
[(1,2)]
```

Comment: I think it should be nubBy instead of nubby. Great solution!

Comment: It is O(n^2). https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub

Answer (score 2):

I feel like I'm repeating myself a bit, but that's okay. None of this code had been tested or even compiled, so there may be bugs. Suppose we can impose an `Ord` constraint for efficiency. I'll start with a limited implementation of sets of pairs.

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

newtype PairSet a b =
  PS (M.Map a (S.Set b))

empty :: PairSet a b
empty = PS M.empty

insert :: (Ord a, Ord b)
       => (a, b) -> PairSet a b -> PairSet a b
insert (a, b) (PS m) = PS $ M.insertWith S.union a (S.singleton b) m

member :: (Ord a, Ord b)
       => (a, b) -> PairSet a b -> Bool
member (a, b) (PS m) =
  case M.lookup a m of
    Nothing -> False
    Just s -> S.member b s
```

Now we just need to keep track of which pairs we've seen.

```
order :: Ord a => (a, a) -> (a, a)
order p@(a, b)
  | a <= b = p
  | otherwise = (b, a)

nubSwaps :: Ord a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
nubSwaps xs = foldr go (`seq` []) xs empty where
  go p r s
    | member op s = r s
    | otherwise = p : r (insert op s)
    where op = order p
```

Answer (score 0):

If a and b are ordered and compareable, you could just do this:

```
[(a,b) | (a,b) <- yourList, a<=b]
```